# An MGF exercise

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, moment-generating-function

I would appreciate some help in the following exercise:

Let the Random Variable $Y$ have the moment generating function $$M(t)=\exp\{q(\theta)-q(\theta+t) \}$$ where $q(.)$ is a function. If $E[Y]=\theta$, prove that that $Y\sim N(\theta,1)$.

**Hint: Consider $M\prime (0) =\theta$ and solve the differential equation.**

---

Starting from $M\prime (0)$ then, we see that $$M\prime (0)=-q \prime (\theta)=\theta $$

A solution of this differential equation is $ q (\theta)=C\exp\{-\theta \}$, with $C$ being a constant which I am having trouble definitizing.

I fear that I have reached a dead end. I think I need to show that the MGF takes the form $\exp\{\theta t +(1/2) t^2 \}$, i.e. the MGF of a normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance $1$. In order to do that, however, I have to definitize the constant which due to the lack of boundary conditions, I don't seem to be able to.

Any advice on how to proceed from here? Thank you.

Comment: *definitizing*?

Comment: @Glen_b The word used in my first calculus class. Unable to part ways with it ever since. Sorry.

Comment: The solutions to $-q^\prime(\theta)=\theta$ are $q(\theta)=-\theta^2/2 + C,$ not $C\exp(-\theta)$.  BTW, most people will not understand what you mean by "definitizing."  I still don't, [even after seeing it used in this context.](http://definitionsinsemantics.blogspot.com/2012/03/humpty-dumpty-principle-in-definitions.html)

Comment: @whuber Mistakingly, I treated it as a first order ODE. What is that particular class of equations called?

Comment: It is a first order ODE :-).  (Technically, it is an ODE of first order that is linear and inhomogeneous.)  I think you simply misread the "$\theta$" on the right hand side as "$q(\theta)$".

Comment: @whuber I think it is the separable kind because we can separate variables and integrate all the way. I should not have missed that, so easy jeez.

Comment: @Glen_b Ah ok. By it I meant the process of assigning a value to the constant term which results from the solution of a differential equation. We usually need a boundary condition for that. Notice that whuber's solution contains a constant term $C$ as well but it cancels as soon as we plug in our solutions to the mgf so we do not need to investigate it further.

Comment: John, thanks. I suppose one could read it as 'making definite' then, which seems to at least suggest the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the moment generating function (mgf) of a random variable $X$ is

$$\phi(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{tX}).$$

*If this exists and is analytic at $t=0$,* it can be expanded into a MacLaurin series (Taylor series at $0$)

$$\phi(t) = 1 + \mathbb{E}(X)t + \frac{t^2}{2}\mathbb{E}(X^2) + \frac{t^3}{3!}\mathbb{E}(X^3) + \cdots + \frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n) + \cdots.$$

Simple operations on $\phi$ yield moments of $X$.  For instance,

$$\phi^\prime(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\phi(t) = \mathbb{E}(X) + \frac{t}{2}\mathbb{E}(X^2)  + \cdots.$$

Evaluating this at $t=0$ yields

$$\phi^\prime(t)|_{t=0} = \mathbb{E}(X) = \theta$$

according to the assumptions of the question.  Let us apply this to the given expression for $\phi$, *adding the assumption that $q$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $\theta$*:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t) = \frac{d}{dt} e^{q(\theta) - q(\theta+t)} = -q^\prime(\theta+t)e^{q(\theta) - q(\theta+t)} .$$

At $t=0$ the argument of the exponential reduces to $q(\theta) - q(\theta)=0$, whence the exponential reduces to unity, leaving

$$\theta = \phi^\prime(0) = -q^\prime(\theta).$$

This is trivial to integrate, with general solution

$$q(\theta) = C - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2.$$

Plugging back in to the mgf simplifies it to

$$\phi(t) =  e^{q(\theta) - q(\theta+t)} = \exp\left(\left(C - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2\right) - \left(C - \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta+t\right)^2\right)\right) = \exp\left(\theta t + \frac{1}{2}t^2\right).$$

A deeper theorem asserts that the unique distribution with this mgf is the Normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and unit variance, *QED*.

Comment: Hello, that was an old question for which you helped me the first time. It doesn't hurt to have a complete answer nevertheless. Thank you.